# Why JSP pages in /WEB-INF folder are not compiled?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jspinclude

Good day, I'm a beginner learning Jave EE. I created a servlet (controller) VersionOverview.java that contains following code in the doGet method:

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/versions.jsp");
view.forward(request, response);
```

File WEB-INF/jsp/versions.jsp contains these lines:

```
<div id="content">
  <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jspf/organization-filter.jspf" />
  ...
</div>
```

File /WEB-INF/jspf/organization-filter.jspf contains these lines:

```
<form name="organization-filter" action="versions">
  <input type="text" id="org_name" name="org_name" value="<%= request.getAttribute("org_name") %>">
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" id="org_id" name="org_id" value="<%= request.getAttribute("org_id") %>">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

When I open page /versions (mapped to the servlet above) it seems that organization-filter.jspf is not compiled because instead of blank input field named org_name I can see this text inside it:

```
<%= request.getAttribute(
```

If I change include directive in the versions.jsp like shown below it starts working:

```
<div id="content">
  <%@include file="/WEB-INF/jspf/organization-filter.jspf" %>
  ...
</div>
```

Please advise why it doesn't work when I use jsp:include. Thank you in advance. Vojtech

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A jspf file is a file that is supposed to be statically included, using an include directive:

```
<%@ include file="someFile.jspf" %>
```

That's just what a JSP <del>fragment</del> segment is, and since it's supposed tobe statically included, there is no point in compiling it.

Here's what the spec says:

> By default the extension .jsp means a top-level JSP file. We
>   recommend, but do not mandate, to differentiate between top-level JSP
>   files (invoked directly by the client or dynamically included by
>   another page or servlet) and statically included segments so that:
>
> - The .jsp
>     extension is used only for files corresponding to top level JSP files,
>     forming a JSP page when processed.
> - Statically included segments use
>     any other extension. As included segments were called ‘JSP fragments’
>     in past versions of this specification, the extension .jspf was
>     offered as a suggestion. This extension is still suggested for
>     consistency reasons, despite that they are now called ‘jsp segments’.

If you want to dynamically include it, then it must have the `.jsp` extension. But in this case, I don't see why you wouldn't use a static include.